# Which radio button selected? Resut display in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, modal-dialog

In first column of the table I have radio buton for each row.

First 3 radio buttons:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input id="1" name="select_row" type="radio">
<input id="2" name="select_row" type="radio">
<input id="3" name="select_row" type="radio">
</form>
```

I would like to read which radio button have been selected and display that in the Modal window.

Button which triger the modal:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Launch Modal</a>
```

In the modal have tried so far those codes:

```
var id = $("input[@name=select_row]:checked").attr('id');
var id = $('input[name=select_row]:checked').attr('id');
var id = $('input[name=select_row]:checked').val();
var id = $("input[name=select_row]:checked").val();  
var id = $('form input[type=radio]:checked');
var id = $('input[name=select_row]:checked', '#myForm').val()

document.write(id);
```

But that display only "undefined" for each of them.

Comment: by modal, do you mean `window.showModalDialog` or a jquery modal?

Comment: Are you running the code each time the modal is opened, or could it be running too early (i.e. before the checkbox has been checked)?  Is the modal a separate page?  Can you reproduce the problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: its jQuery modal created in "Bootstrap". Modal window code it's just below table with radio buttons. When you load the page non of the radio button is selected. Should the modal be as a separate page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: for this to work your model and form should be on the same HTML page.

```
alert($('#myForm').find("input:radio:checked").attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qNSCn/

```
<form id="myForm">
<input id="1" name="select_row" type="radio">
<input id="2" name="select_row" type="radio">
<input id="3" name="select_row" type="radio">
</form>
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="link" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Launch Modal</a>
```

​And for the jQuery code:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    var x = $('#myForm input[type=radio]:checked').attr('id');
    console.log(x);
});​
```